# BUILD FAILED in 7s Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'.. Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: exception, gradle

Please I have a Gradle problem here I use the gradle version 7.6.1, and I have java jdk 21, I also changed the Gradle version to 8.4 to try but it still doesn't work, please guide me. Thanks in advance.

I tried
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pu upgrade
flutter run